# Retrofit response is always null

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp, github-api

I'm trying to get user name from gitHub Api but retrofit response return always null. When I'm trying to show user name in toast I see : null. I tried change retrofit path but it didn't work. Everything looks fine but I don't know why I get this error all the time.

```
interface GitHubApi{

@GET("/users/{user}")
fun getUser(@Path("user") user: String): Call<User>

companion object Factory {
    fun getClient(): GitHubApi {
        val url = "https://api.github.com/"

        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            .apply { level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY }

        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()

        return retrofit.create(GitHubApi::class.java)
    }
}}
```

user model:

```
data class User(val userName: String)
```

MainActivity:

```
    private fun createApiService() : GitHubApi{
    val url = "https://api.github.com/"

    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        .apply { level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY }

    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .build()

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(url)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()

    return retrofit.create(GitHubApi::class.java)
}

private fun loadData() {
    val api  = GitHubApi.getClient()

    api.getUser("fabpot").enqueue(object : Callback<User> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<User>, t: Throwable) {
            t.printStackTrace()
        }

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<User>,
            response: Response<User>
        ) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                runOnUiThread { showErrorMessage(response.code().toString()) }
            }

            response.body()?.let { showErrorMessage(it.repoName) }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the log when you make the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no key userName exist in github api.

try editing your data class this way.

```
data class User(val name: String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the beginning slash "/" in your `@GET` method.